# Would 'findAll()' in MongoDB ever return a null result in Grails?

Tags: mongodb, grails

I know this might seem like an odd question, but was just wondering if anyone knew (or came across) a case where this has happened. Debugging a server issue where this might be happening and wanted to either eliminate it as a cause, or look into it further.

And also, if the answer is yes, why would this happen?

Comment: what driver you are working with? there is no findAll() method in mongo, in some drivers findAll() is equal to find({})

Comment: and you get the right answer from mongodb shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't - all query methods that can return multiple results return a `List` (typically just a vanilla `java.util.ArrayList`) which is either empty or has results. If you're getting a null result, something's very broken.